# What is the trick to create 4 layer Chapati?

Tags: flour

More layers' chapati tastes delicious and looks soft. What is the trick to create 4 layers' chapati?

[image: Chapati]

What I have tried --

1. Before rolling the chapati, I have made 2 folds by putting few drops of
   oil in between the folds.
2. I rolled in similar fashion at all over the edges and middle
   portion.

Till the date, I could make 3 layers' chapati but not 4 layers. I have tried more folds also before rolling the chapati but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Layers depends on type of flour you are using. I suppose if you are using wheat flour, then before each folding add some cooking oil between folds. Repeat this process for each extra layer. Remember to add cooking oil in each fold to make sure that do not stick together again. Roll it gently, do not apply to much force. 
To understand more about layer Chapati,
[Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChPOYG6z9n8)